# Get pictures from Panoramio accrording to bounding box

Tags: coordinates, bounding-box, panoramio

Unfortunatly I am new to programming issues and need a clarification regarding panoramio APIs. I have the following generic link:
http://www.panoramio.com/map/get_panoramas.php?set=7000000&from=0&to=10&minx=-180&miny=-90&maxx=180&maxy=90&size=mini_square

This basically allows me to obtain set of metadata in txt-format related to images appearing in this specific Panoramio bounding box.
QUESTION:
Obviously I require a specifc bounding box with different minx, miny and maxx and maxy values. Although changing this values does not provide any different result. Can somebody tell me a way through it or make a short example?

thanks for any explaination,
Daniel, Italy

Answer (score 0):

Your request looks malformed.
if you read the documentation in http://www.panoramio.com/api/data/api.html you see that accepted values for "set" are:

- **public** (popular photos)
- **full** (all photos)
- **user ID number**

So at least you have to change the "set" value to one accepted.
Then add the coordinates of the lower left and upper right corner of your bounding box following carefully the guidelines in the above mentioned web page:
*"the minx, miny, maxx, maxy define the area to show photos from (minimum longitude, latitude, maximum longitude and latitude, respectively).*"